# Load text column to postgres

Tags: postgresql, copy, aws-aurora, load

I use the following to load data into postgres

```
\copy tab FROM /tmp/file DELIMITER E'\t' QUOTE E'\b' NULL AS '\N' CSV
```

Usually I select the data from a source db

```
echo "select * from tab" | mysql --batch --quick --skip-column-names .... > /tmp/file
```

It generates a file with tab delimiter fields. It works well for the most part. Up until I try to import multi line text column.
The error comes on:

```
ERROR:  unquoted carriage return found in data
```

Any recommendations how to overcome this?

Comment: Your export format is broken, or at least doesn't match your import format. You haven't told us anything about the export, so what can we say other than 'fix it'?

Comment: The way I get it involves posting here a long question, however, I edit it with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql command you show seems (experimentally, not from actual knowledge) to generate output which is compatible with PostgreSQL's TEXT format, not the CSV format.  Newlines are represented by the two characters `\n`, tabs by `\t`, and literal backslashes by `\\`.

So try to import it in that format, which is the default:

```
\copy tab FROM /tmp/file
```

Comment: I think what breaks the import is `^M`, can that be?

Comment: More specifically, I believe, something here(part of text): `URL variables:\n\t\t\t^M\n<!-- == dump-begin x1nn0o == format: modern !-->^M\n<div id="-app-dump-x1nn0o"`

Comment: Yes, mysql reports the ^M literally, rather than converting into two-character escape sequence `\r`, so in that character it is not compatible with PostgreSQL's text format.  You can pipe the data through `sed 's/\r/\\r/g'` to fix that.

Comment: Looking good, what all the characters that can breaks the import? For example I have a suspicion now it fails on `^[`

Comment: I think I need to escape all the special ones, `^[` is not the only one

Comment: I don't know, I only tried with \t \n \\ and then \r.  Presumably you could find a better specification in the mysql docs someplace, but I failed at that.  Or you might want to use a tool better suited to the task, like mysqldump or TO OUTFILE.

Comment: OK, so a broader solution is (except `\0`,`\n`,`\t`) - `sed 's/[\x04-\x08\x0B-\x1F\x7F]/ /g'`. if you can add this to the answer so it will cover everything :)